# std::cin working for small number of lines, but not larger ones

Tags: c++, list, import, filenames, cin

I'm writing a part of a program that takes a list of filenames provided by the user and stores them in a vector. So far, testing with small numbers of filenames (I've done up to 11) works fine and the program continues, but trying to import 70 or more filenames makes it so that the program will not continue.

Here is my code:

```
//******************************* Get List of Filenames ********************************
cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
cout << "Please paste all of the Scans files here: ";
vector<string> filenameList;
string filenameString;

//can change the quit value to anything you want
while (cin >> filenameString && filenameString != "b") 
{
    filenameList.push_back(filenameString);
}

cout << "The filenames entered are:\n";
for (int i = 0; i < filenameList.size(); i++)
{
    cout << filenameList[i] << endl;
}
cout << endl << filenameList.size();
```

The error is that the program hangs and looks like it is still waiting for input, but does not do anything else, even after entering the exit code "b".

We are copying and pasting the filenames directly into the console and then using `cin` to put them into a vector.

Here is an example of a list of the filenames that we are using:

```
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p001.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p002.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p003.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p004.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p005.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p006.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p007.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p008.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p009.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p010.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p011.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p012.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p013.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p014.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p015.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p016.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p017.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p018.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p019.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p020.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p021.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p022.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p023.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p024.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p025.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p026.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p027.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p028.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p029.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p030.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p031.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p032.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p033.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p034.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p035.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p036.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p037.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p038.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p039.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p040.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p041.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p042.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p043.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p044.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p045.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p046.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p047.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p048.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p049.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p050.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p051.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p052.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p053.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p054.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p055.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p056.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p057.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p058.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p059.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p060.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p061.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p062.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p063.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p064.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p065.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p066.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p067.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p068.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p069.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p070.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p071.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p072.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p073.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p074.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p075.jpg
MSS279_S10_B112_F8_p076.jpg
```

Comment: What exactly is the error your seeing?  Also, I wouldn't use "b" to end the stream, you could just check cin for EOF (since I'm assuming your piping files via the command line, there isn't much of a use for this type of application other than that)

Comment: What do you mean by 'not continue'? Does the program crash? Or does it hang?

Comment: Or does it finish with incomplete list of filenames?

Comment: Most likely, the issue is with the way you are pasting the filenames and not with the program. For example, if the stuff you paste does not end with a newline, a subsequent `b` will not be read as ending the list.

Comment: Why are you using cin.ignore? Nevertheless, with and without cin.ignore this seems to be working correctly. How are you giving the input to the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out why, but I think there is a limit to the number of characters Xcode could import for some reason (somewhere around 1000 characters).

I switched over to Visual Studio on a PC and everything worked out perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

Try separating `cin >> filenameString && filenameString != "b"` into two lines of code.  Maybe put the second part inside the loop, in an `if` statement like this:  `if (filenameString != "b") break;`  I have a suspicion that assigning to `filenameString` and then comparing it in the same line may not always behave as you think it should.

Comment: I separated the line, but it still does not work with large numbers of files. Here is the edited code: while (cin >> filenameString) 
            {
                if (filenameString == "b")
                {
                    break;
                }
                filenameList.push_back(filenameString);
            }

Comment: I guess that wasn't it then.  Try this: run your program in debug mode, and start pasting in file names.  Pause every so often and verify that the strings in your vector are correct.  When your program hangs, pause again and check what line it's hanging on.  Also check the value of `filenameString`.

Comment: So it gets to p036, then after that looks like it is stuck on the first line of the while loop. As I step through the debugger, it goes through a lot of pages that look like spreadsheets of different error codes... The vector is all correct up through p036 and the filenameString at the end is stuck at the p036 filename...

Comment: It looks like when I pause the debugger while the program is hung, it pauses on this line: 0x7fff8ad9ae9a:  jae    0x7fff8ad9aea4            ; __write_nocancel + 20. When I click play again, it jumps to a point in previous code and goes into an infinite loop... I don't know why it went backwards in the code.

Comment: So, I thought that the number of characters might be an issue, and when pasting in enough filenames to approach 1000 characters, that is when it goes wrong. If I paste in 36 filenames, then paste in another 36, it will capture all of them no problem, but if I do 37 the program starts to not respond.

Comment: Ok, check for a failed input from the stream.  Put this code in your `while` loop:  `if (cin.fail()) {cout << "Failed read from cin" << endl;}` and also put a breakpoint on that line so you can pause when/if it fails.

Comment: I added the fail line and the breakpoint as the first if statement in the loop, but still get the same thing

Comment: Sorry, that's all I got.  Does the code fail on *any* 37 lines, or just the ones you're testing?  If only the one you're testing, I would look closely at that last line to make sure there aren't wierd characters in it or something.

Comment: Any 37 lines, I've tried multiple folders of images. I think it may have something to do with the number of characters, maybe a limitation in my version of xcode. I'm going to try it with visual studio once I get to a PC